# How do I bind combobox text to legacy data not in the drop down list?

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding, multibinding

The drop-down list (itemssource) of my combobox contains new product request items. **I want to bind to legacy data that is not in the drop-down list.** To complicate things I'm using multibinding with an IMultiValueConverter to combine fields for display. Also, the names of bound fields do not match the names of the properties I'm bound to.

The combobox itemssource is a list of NewProductRequests. From this NPR object NewProdNumber and NewProdName are combined for display in the drop-down list by my type converter. The ConvertBack method returns the values NewProdNumber and NewProdNumberCombinedWithName. These two values will be saved to database fields with slightly different names. For this example I'll call them DBProdRequestNumber and DBProdRequestTitle.

I've succeeded in displaying and saving new items. **The problem is I haven't figured out how to display legacy data that is not in the list**. It's not in the list because it no longer qualifies as a *new* product request.

Here is the problem XAML (the itemssource is set in code-behind):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="NPRComboBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsEditable="False">
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource combineNPRStuffMultiConverter}">
            <Binding Path="DBProdRequestNumber" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            <Binding Path="DBProdRequestTitle" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource combineNPRStuffMultiConverter}">                             
                        <Binding Path="NewProdNumber" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>                              
                        <Binding Path="NewProdNumberCombinedWithName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

A similar problem with a datagrid and combobox I solved using a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate based on [this MSDN Magazine example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983481.aspx) from Julie Lerman. Of course, in this case I'm not using a datagrid.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ?  I'm having the same kind of requirement here...

Comment: See my accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer (to my own question) was pulled from a comment in the NathanAW answer:

Unfortunately I can't include legacy items in the ItemsSource. The list is from a web service that is out of my control. I devised a kludgy solution which I don't really like (but it works)...Since I know the combobox is needed only for new records it is visible only when the user clicks "Add". In the same location I placed a textbox bound to the legacy data that is visible when NOT in add mode. So, I toggle the visiblity of each control as the app switches in and out of add mode. I'm sure there is a better way!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Typically the one I didn't want to read :-)  I think I will use a textblock displaying the old value, and a popup showing the "new" items when this textblock is clicked. (it would also allow late-binding on this list, which is my other requirement...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might be able to simplify this by not using a Multi-Binding converter. If you have a collection of NPR objects, then you can set that as the ItemsSource for the listbox. Then use the DataTemplate to format how you want that item displayed.

With this setup, you can construct a template that shows multiple fields from the NPR object in a single TextBlock using something like:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="NPRComboBox" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
    IsEditable="False" 
    SelectedItem={Binding SelectedNPR, Mode=TwoWay}" 
>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
               <Run Text="{Binding Path=NewProdNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
               <Run> - </Run>
               <Run Text="{Binding Path=NewProdNumberCombinedWithName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If you have additional properties on the NPR object that you'd like to access, you can add an additional section to the template.

Notice that the "selected" item is bound two-way back to a property on your ViewModel (or code-behind, or whatever). This would be something like:

```
public NPR SelectedNPR
{
   get { ... }
   set 
   {
       ...
       // don't forget INotifyPropertyChanged
       ...
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a sample that seems to do what you've indicted about showing legacy data in the "SelectionBox", but not in the drop down list. To test this, try running it in KaXaml or something. Then start typing "Hello 3" and see that it suggests "Hello 30". This indicates that the Combo knows about the item. Now drop the list down and see that it isn't in the list. If you arrow down with the arrow keys, it skips from "Hello 20" to "Hello 40".

The next step would be to setup your templates so that the ListBoxItem template's Visibility is bound to "IsLegacy" on your NPR object. Then add both legacy and new items to the ItemsSource collection and bind to the list.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
  <ComboBoxItem >Hello 10</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem >Hello 20</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem Visibility="Collapsed">Hello 30</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem >Hello 40</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I implemented your solution just now and still have the original problem. Legacy data from the database is not displayed since it's not in the drop down list. Your  solution is a good way to avoid the convert portion of a type converter. However, I still require the TC's ConvertBack method (I think) to split the selecteditem into two values to be saved to the DBProdRequestNumber and DBProdRequestTitle fields. I need to show a drop-down of NewProdNumber combined with name. When selected, save each value to separate database fields. Allow legacy values not in the list to show in the text area.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "Legacy data not in the drop down list"? I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. Is this data that the users type in manually?

Comment: We keep a record of all requests for new products to be developed at our company. Some requests are closed once the product is developed or deemed not viable. As new requests arrive the drop-down will only displays requests that are new. Still, I need to show historic data if the user wants to display an old closed product request. As a new record is added the user will pick from the new requests in the drop-down. Yet if the user wants to see an old record the text portion of the combobox should display the old product request info (even though it is no longer in the list).

Comment: I think I understand. What if you add a property to the NPR object called "IsLegacy". Then include both legacy and new items in the ItemsSource bound collection. Then in your DataTemplate you bind Visibility to IsLegacy so that Legacy items are "collapsed" in the list. Lastly, set up a datatemplate for the selection box via the "SelectionBotItemTemplate so that you can show proper values for new or legacy. This would allow the "Selection Box" portion of the combo to display all items, but eliminate the legacy from the drop down list. I'll try to test and add code if I have a second.

Comment: Added a sample to show what you describe in the previous comment.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't include legacy items in the ItemsSource. The list is from a web service that is out of my control. I devised a kludgy solution which I don't really like (but it works)...Since I know the combobox is needed only for new records it is visible only when the user clicks "Add". In the same location I placed a textbox bound to the legacy data that is visible when NOT in add mode. So, I toggle the visiblity of each control as the app switches in and out of add mode. I'm sure there is a better way! Thanks for your help. You helped me learn something new.